# More KDE-esque audio control in Ubuntu/GNOME menu bar? or PulseAudio-cum-Gnome integration?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, kde, gnome-shell, menu-bar

KDE's volume/audio options on the system bar looks like this:
[image: screenshot]

It allows easy management of each application's volume and output. GNOME's system menu only features a volume slider for the currently selected audio output. More functionality is found in *Settings* > *Sound*. Not only is this inconvenient, it lacks any way to change audio output on a per application basis. You can only select one output at a time, for all applications. To change each audio outputs per application in Gnome, software like PulseAudio Volume Control is required. This is not convenient and annoying, since it's easy to accidentally adjust the wrong settings by scrolling through them in PulseAudio.

I am looking for a way to implement a KDE-esque audio control for Ubuntu/GNOME system menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481) called '[**Volume Mixer**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/858/volume-mixer/)'.

> Shell Volume Mixer is an extension for GNOME Shell allowing separate configuration of PulseAudio devices and output switches. It features a profile switcher to quickly switch between pinned profiles and devices.
>   [image]

Comment: Thank you pomsky, this helps a lot.
https://extensions.gnome.org/ is great, wonder what other sites i'm oblivious to. It is still missing the ability to change outputs per application, but much easier than stock.